# Extraction Event

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, extract, web-testing

So I have the following code:

```
    public override void Extract(object sender, ExtractionEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.Response.HtmlDocument != null)
            {

                var myParam = e.Request.QueryStringParameters.Where(parameter => parameter.Name == QueryName).Select(parameter => parameter.Value).Distinct();

                myParam.

                // add the extracted value to the web performance test context
                e.WebTest.Context.Add(this.ContextParameterName, myParam.ToString());
                e.Success = true;
                return;

            }


        // If the extraction fails, set the error text that the user sees
        e.Success = false;
        e.Message = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Not Found: {0}", QueryName);
    }
```

It's returning:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+<DistinctItem>d_81`1[system.string]
```

I am expecting something along the lines of:

```
0152-1231-1231-123d
```

My question is how do I extract the querystring's actual value from `extractioneventargs`.  They say it's possible, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `string.Join`:

```
string resultAsString = string.Join("-", myParam);
e.WebTest.Context.Add(this.ContextParameterName, resultAsString);
```

I'm assuming here that the query string parameter values are *0152*, *1231*, etc, and you want to combine them with dashes.

Since [`WebTest.Context.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244024%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) can accept an object, you could also add the result as an array, if that suits your purposes:

```
e.WebTest.Context.Add(this.ContextParameterName, myParam.ToArray());
```

---

(Note that this string ``` System.Linq.Enumerable+<DistinctItem>d_81``1[system.string] ``` is the type name, which is what `ToString()` returns for any object by default (unless it's been overridden).)